# How to automatically scale a custom View with ShapeDrawables?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I am writing a custom view for my Android application, that consists of several `ShapeDrawables`. For these drawables, I have to specify the dimensions using `setBounds()`. Now, my view will always be square, but I want it to use as much space as I allow it within the parent where it is embedded.

So, right now I call `setBounds()` with some hardcoded values, but when I specify `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height`, I want my `ShapeDrawables` to be scaled so that they appear as large as possible.

How can I accomplish this within my custom View class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it myself:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    mSize = Math.min(width, height);

    setMeasuredDimension(mSize, mSize);
}
```